# WAMP nice URL's redirect to direct file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Hello when I trying nice url with htaccess it's redirecting to file, so when I type www.page.com/mainpage it's redirect to www.page.com/mainpage.php and not to www.page.com/index.php?arg1=mainpage

my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?arg1=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ ?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ ?arg1=$1&arg2=$2&arg3=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the `MultiViews` enabled. Also, your rewrites are not referencing `index.php` anywhere. Try the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?arg1=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2&arg3=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Work's nice! Just tell me why this option? I don't understand that much...

Comment: @PavelKocfelda https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_negotiation#multiviews